# Meteor - mrt add [package] with dependencies

Tags: meteor, meteorite, atmosphere

I have weird problem with 'mrt add' for packages with dependencies.

1. I have created new app with 'meteor create myapp' (meteor 0.7.2)
2. I wanted to add my package with scss package as a dependency.. all is ok (there is packages/scss and my package and also main smart.lock got scss settings, but in .meteor/packages there is only my package listed)
3. If I run app by 'meteor' Scss compiling don't work
4. If I add scss line to .meteor/packages and rerun everything is ok.
5. I tested this with 'iron-router-progress' which has 'iron-router' as a dependency and effect is the same

Why this is happening? Some kind of mrt bug?

Comment: Is your package on atmosphere? If not you are supposed to use `meteor add [package]`. Or did you try `mrt update`?

Comment: Yes this is on atmosphere. I also tried mrt update. It looks like mrt don't install any dependent packages but it only downloading files and updating smart.lock only. This is wierd.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, July 2014, the answer is that you need to use `api.imply(['scss'])` in your `package.js` file (note, this is the Meteor package file, not the Atmosphere package file).

For an example see [the package.js file for standard-app-packages](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/a933225026fa8646d4d6d892fd501b48395cae8e/packages/standard-app-packages/package.js).

You'll probably also want to add it to `packages` in your package's `smart.json`.

This will all probably be changing soon, and hopefully will become documented.